# Связь с обзора полем полезности Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть сервис обзора фильмов, в каждом фильме есть `review` (отзыв, обзор) таблица, связанная с фильмом с помощью belongsToMany.

Под каждым `review` будут кнопки `useful` и `not useful`.

При нажатии кнопки `useful` необходимо:

- Добавить строку в связующую таблицу
- В таблице `review` добавлять +1 к полю `helpfulness`

При нажатии на `not useful`:

- Удалить строку из связующей таблицы
- В таблице `review` отнять -1 от поля `helpfulness`

Таблца review:

```
Schema::create('reviews', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('helpfulness')->nullable();
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('movie_id');
        $table->float('rating');
        $table->text('text')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

Необходимо: создать таблицу, связывающую `review` и `user`

Comment: А вопрос в чем?

Comment: необходимо сделать таблицу)